# How do I loop through the rows in a Dataview in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, rows, dataview

I need to loop through the rows in a DataView so I can get the data or object from the row to add to a listbox. Here is my code for the DataView. The RowFilter is set to only extract the data for a row if the ID that the user entered matches the "CustomerID" field. How do I loop through the Rows that have been added to create a temporary object for the data in the row?

```
'create new table for storing incident data
        Dim incidentTable As DataView = CType(incidentsDataSource.Select(
        DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty), DataView)
        incidentTable.RowFilter = ("CustomerID = '" & custIDTextBox.Text & "'") 
        Dim incidentRow As DataRowView = incidentTable(0)

        'declare temporary incident and store all data in corresponding fields
        Dim incident As New Incident
        With incident
            .IncidentID = incidentRow("IncidentID").ToString
            .CustomerID = incidentRow("CustomerID").ToString
            .ProductCode = incidentRow("ProductCode").ToString
            .TechID = incidentRow("TechID").ToString
            .DateOpened = incidentRow("DateOpened").ToString
            .DateClosed = incidentRow("DateClosed").ToString
            .Title = incidentRow("Title").ToString
        End With
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DataView` itself IS a list; a list of `DataRowView` objects to be precise.  You simply loop through the `DataView` itself, e.g.

```
For Each row As DataRowView In myDataView
    Dim name = CStr(row("Name"))
    '...
Next
```